# Access columns and rows of numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I currently struggling with extracting certain columns and rows from a matrix stored as a numpy.ndarray.

I have a list in which I've appended these numpy.ndarrays.

This list is stored in a variable named `data`

```
print data[0].shape
```

outputs this

```
(400, 288)
```

Which I've according to the documentation have understood being the matrix has 400 rows, and 288 columns.

How do I extract all the 288 seperately?

Example:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> data = np.random.rand(3,3)
>> print data

[[ 0.97522481  0.57583658  0.68582806]
 [ 0.88509883  0.22261933  0.84307038]
 [ 0.59397925  0.51592125  0.54346909]]
```

How do I print the columns separately of this 3x3 matrix, first being

```
[0.97522481 , 0.88509883, 0.59397925 ]
```

without outputting the others?

Comment: A short example describing the desired behavior would be helpful

Comment: Depending on the use case, you might not need to separate out the columns as you can simply slice - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Comment: `data[:,0]` to look at the 1st column

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 2], 
                [3, 4], 
                [5, 6]])
print(arr.shape)
# (3, 2)
print(list(data.T))
# [array([1, 3, 5]), array([2, 4, 6])]
```