# How do I easily convert a numpy.ndarray to a list of numpy.array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am currently struggling to  parsing some data into a training framework.

The problem is that the framework is not able to handle ndarray. I need to convert into a list of array. The input and output data is currently stored as two seperate lists of numpy.ndarray.

1. The input data has to be converted into a list of numpy array where each array contains a column of the ndarray.
2. The output data has to be converted into a list of numpy arrays where each array contains the rows of the ndarray?..

Is it possible to convert it to this?

when i print train_output_data[0] i get this:

https://ufile.io/fa816

Comment: As listed in your previous [`Q&A`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566500/access-columns-and-rows-of-numpy-ndarray), use `list(a)` and `list(a.T)`?

Comment: I am not sure i understand how transposing will help here?

Comment: Transpose brings the second axis along which we have the cols as the first axis and thus when *put* into `list()` would create a list of cols. Why not try it out? If it doesn't solve it, how about put a sample array and the expected list of arrays?

Comment: @Divakar thanks for the explanation! I don't see it benefitting the problem if i do it on both, I gues only one have to do it.. But which one.  Is the listed numpy.array stored row by row or column by column?

Comment: @CarltonBanks Can't you just try it?  E.g. `a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]); list1 = list(a); list2 = list(a.T)` and then see which one is the one you want.  You can do that in an interactive python session, or even better, an ipython session.

Comment: I guess the transposing just the output is the solution i was seeking for..  it seems that numpy.ndarrays make list of each row of en matrix. So transposing it, made both input and output have the correct dimensions.

Comment: Is the print statement printing *everything* in the file including the lines `Preprocessing
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
cen7-mwhw-b
mwhw-b-cen7`? Do you want to convert all instances of train_output_data? What is it's size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ip` and `op` are the input list and output lists respectively,

```
newInput = [ip[:,i] for i in range(ip.shape[0])]
newOutput = [x for x in op]
```

If the `train_output_data` and `train_input_data` are lists of 2D `numpy.ndarray`'s, then the alternative can be

```
newInput = []
for ip in train_input_data:
    newInput.append([ip[:,i] for i in range(ip.shape[0])])

newOutput = []
for op in train_output_data:
    newOutput.append([x for x in op])
```

Comment: I guess you have to add an outer for-loop for to make it run for a list with multiple ndarrays.

Comment: @CarltonBanks: You stated that *the input and output data is currently stored as two separate lists of numpy.ndarray.* If there are only two lists, one for each of input and output, then the above two lines would suffice.

Comment: oh... yeah but  ip.shape[0] cannot be called. 
as the ndarrays are appended to a list.   You can call ip.shape[0].shape[0].. 
But this will then only work for that one instance?

Comment: @CarltonBanks I need to know the dimension and datatype specification of your inputs. By a list of ndarrays, do you mean a list of 2D arrays or a list of 1D arrays? Could you give an example set of input-outputs?

Comment: I added an example output i get by printing train_output_data[0]